# Putting extensions in a certificate in OpenSSL

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I need to put extensions in a certificate like this in the picture, I tried many ways, but I can not.

[image: OK Image]

I'm running:

```
"#openssl req -new  -keyout $nomerepre.key -out $nomerepre.csr -passin pass:$senha -config myconfig.cnf"

"#openssl x509 -req  -days 365  -in $nomerepre.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 10102014 -out $nomerepre.crt -passin pass:$senha -extfile myconfig.cnf  -extensions v3_req"
```

---

My configuration file is thus below
myconfigssl.conf

```
oid_section = OIDs

[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
encrypt_key = no
default_md = sha1
distinguished_name = dn
req_extensions = v3_req

[ OIDs ]
MyOID=2.16.76.1.3.4



    [ dn ]
    CN = John Smith
    emailAddress = john.smith@quovadisglobal.com
    O = QuoVadis Group
    C = US



[v3_req]
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8=ASN1:UTF8String:Something
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
#subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
MyOID = 00000000111111111112222222222233333333333444444
2.16.76.1.3.4 = 00000000111111111112222222222233333333333444444
```

Unfortunately the result that this is going:

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you got no extensions as shown in EG2Oa.jpg. You should have extension `1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8` there. SubjectAltName is commented so it should not be in the certificate.

I tried using [xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca) which uses OpenSSL 1.0.2d as show in the picture
[image: xca about]

I used this config

```
# if it should be a separate extension
2.16.76.1.3.4=ASN1:UTF8String:Some random data

#if it should be a part of subjectAltName
subjectAltName=@subject_alt_section

[subject_alt_section]
otherName=2.16.76.1.3.4;UTF8:Some random data
```

And I got this certificate

[image: generated certificate]

---

Now some theory. I don't know where this extension should be placed. If it is a separate extension or if it should be a part of SubjectAltName. I don't know if the extension should be an UTF8String or OctetString or a Sequence of something.

If you want a separate extension you can use `2.16.76.1.3.4=ASN1:UTF8String:Some random data` as you already tried. More on arbitrary extensions can be found [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/x509v3_config.html).

This extension can be part of subjectAltName according to [the description](http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=2.16.76.1.3.4&action=display) of the oid. Definition of otherName can be found in [RFC5280 in section 4.2.1.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6). If so then this config worked for me

```
subjectAltName=@subject_alt_section

[subject_alt_section]
otherName=2.16.76.1.3.4;UTF8:Some random data
```

Using the above mentioned config I've got structure of the certificate as shown in the picture below. [ASN1Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor) was used to show the structure.

[image: Asn1 structure of the certificate]