# Can openssl prompt for custom fields like it does normal fields?

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509

It is possible to embed string values into custom fields in x509 certificates using openssl as answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417627/putting-extensions-in-a-certificate-in-openssl) show. The only problem with the given solution is that the value is hardcoded into the config file. Ideally I would like to manage values just like `openssl` handles something like country name, specifically:

1. Define the OID as corresponding to a UTF8 String value
2. Mark the OID as required
3. provide a default value and Min/Max character lengths
4. Admins will be prompted to add this value or it can be imported via environment variable

Is it possible to add framework using openssl config file and avoid hardcoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For 'fields' in the Subject DistinguishedName (DN) YES.** See [the man page for `req` at the heading Distinguished Name and Attribute Section Format](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/req.html#DISTINGUISHED-NAME-AND-ATTRIBUTE-SECTION-FORMAT) . Note for prompted fields you don't specify the ASN.1 type; they automatically use the 'DirectoryString' logic which nowadays (post-5280) is normally either PrintableString or UTF8String depending on the characters in the content.

**For extensions**, which are the subject of the Q you linked, **not directly**.
On some Unix shells, you can have a *shell script* prompt for value(s) and feed it(them) as part of an automatically created temporary file used as the config file using process substitution `<( ... )`.

In addition *both* unprompted Subject fields and extensions can be read from environment variables, which also can be set by a shell script (in pretty much every shell ever), or on Windows a BAT or PS1. See [the man page for `config`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html)

emailAddress is a special case. It can occur in the Subject (DN) or in the SubjectAltName extension (SAN) or both. `req` can put a prompted value in the Subject of a cert but not SAN. However, if you generate a CSR not a cert, and subsequently use that CSR to obtain a cert -- which was clearly the case in the linked Q because it is not selfsigned, and a cert generated by `req -new -x509` is -- then the CSR creation can put a prompted value for emailAddress in the proposed Subject, and if the CSR is processed by `openssl ca` *that* can move or copy emailAddress from Subject to SAN; see the man pages for `ca` and as referenced `x509v3_config`.

Comment: any chance you can link to an example of the `<( ...)` being used?

Comment: actually turns out I using `easy-rsa` I just need to use `$ENV::MYVARNAME` and I can get the value into the generated config file.